# Issue with extracting element values from an object array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, generics

***Question background:***

I have an object hierarchy that contains an object array of object arrays. I have written the classes to correctly deserialize this object from its JSON representation.

The code:

```
var list = new People
{
    PersonList = new object[]
    {
      new object[]
     {
       "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", null, new Person{Name="John", Age=21}, 1
     },
      new object[]
     {
       "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", null, null, 2
     },
     new object[]
     {
       "Test17", "Test8", "Test9", null, new Person{Name="Sara", Age=31}, 3
     },
        new object[]
     {
       "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", null, null, 4
     },
     new object[]
     {
         "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", null, new Person{Name="John", Age=31}, 5
     }
     }
};

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

var objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(output);

objectList = objList.PersonList;

foreach (var objectItem in objectList)
{

   //Extract elements from the looped 'objectItem' array.

}
```

**The issue:**

Currently I cannot seem to extract the data from the individual object array. The for loop above allows access to each object array but I cannot get the elements within it.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to proceed to extract this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to define what type the item is in the loop:

```
foreach (JArray objectItem in objectList)
{
    // extract them by index
    var val1 = objectItem[0];
}
```

As stated by James, you could also loop through the internal `object[]` just like you are the outer one.

Comment: Yep, the problem is `objectList` is an array of `object` therefore `objectItem` will be treated as such, it would need cast (or like you say, explicitly defined) so you can index into it's properties. Alternatively, you could have another loop...

Comment: @Micheal Perrenoud Thanks for the replies. Currently when i change the object property to its actual type of the object array I'm receiving this error on the loop: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in HouseTest.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Object[]'.

Comment: @user1352057, please see my edit. The `JArray` class has an indexer just like the `object[]`.http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm

Comment: Perfect! I saw your edit and got it straight away. I can now access all of the properties.